# Facebook App first hurdle

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, facebook-c#-sdk

I am falling at the first hurdle with facebook c# SDK.

I am using Visual Studio 2010, I have frame work 4 and using c#

I have downloaded the codeplex c# SDK zip and build the world simplest app.

I cannot for the life of me get the FacebookApp object to be recognised.

I have references to the Facebook.dll and Facebook.Web.dll and have using calls to both namespaces in the class, but I cannot get the code to run.

I found the dlls were marked as "potentially dangerous" and solved this, but no dice. I am sure I am being dumb but I am about to give up

```
using System;
using Facebook;
using Facebook.Web;

namespace FacebookTest
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var app = new FacebookApp();
            dynamic me = app.Get("me");
            string firstName = me.first_name;
            string lastName = me.last_name;
            string email = me.email;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors specifically are you seeing?  Compile errors?  Runtime errors?  You need to give more details and ask a specific question.

Comment: ok, specifically I was using the .NET 4.0 dlls from the bin folder in the SDK codeplex download. When I removed them and used the 3.5 framework dlls the code compiled. My specific question was why will the following code not run. I have now solved this problem, the code runs.

Comment: However the app.Get("me") fails with 400 error. This is not at all fun. Can we consider this one closed for the time being

Comment: Maybe your project is configured to build for .Net Framework 4 Client Profile or some other Framework version different from 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this as I was using the wrong dlls depsite copying over them multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things:

- Download a new copy of the SDK from
  codeplex (make sure it is the latest
  version)
- Right click on the zip file, click
  properties, the select the 'unlock'
  button
- Extract the zip file and
  completely replace all your
  references with the references in the
  newly extracted folder
- Ensure that
  your application is running .Net 4.0
  (not client profile) or .Net 3.5 (if
  you are using the .Net 3.5 builds.
- Make sure your project is in a folder
  that you normally work in (probably
  something on the C drive)

If these don't work, please provide more information regarding your error.

Comment: Thanks, I found that I had some dlls "stuck" in my project from the old api. They were also locked. I am underway now, but this is a slog. Thanks for your help